# openlitespeed mongodb extension installation for lsphp

Tags: php, php.ini, litespeed

I'm trying to use mongodb with lsphp. Currently I've manually compiled mongodb.so following [this](http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.installation.manual.php) and I can see `mongodb.so` at  `/usr/local/lsws/lsphp7/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303` . Now, next step in the link is to enable the extension by adding `extension=mongodb.so` line at `php.ini`. The problem is that I couldn't find `php.ini` for the lsphp7.1 version that was compiled with `openlitespeed` admin GUI. I've searched each folder in `/usr/local/lsws/lsphp7` with no result for `php.ini`.

[Screenshot of phpinfo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MqHqT.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like no php.ini file is present for the PHP version - what you can do, is to go to `/usr/local/lsws/lsphp7/lib` and in there put a file called php.ini with the content from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/php/php-src/PHP-7.1.25/php.ini-production

There you can also add your `extension=mongodb.so` in the bottom of the ini file.

Remember to restart OpenLiteSpeed afterward!

I'm investigating why there's no default php.ini file and will update/comment on my reply whenever I know more!